# How To Do Mathematical calculation on a previously saved mysql data and new form input data in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form with an input field that would update data on a mysql table column on submission. 
Here is the table:- [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XklJ.png)

Here is my form:-

```
<form name=updateamount method=post>
<table width="500" >
    <tr>
      <td width="161">New Due Amount: </td>
      <td width="329"><label>
        <input name="new_due" type="text" class="StyleTxtField" id="new_due">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
  <td><div align="center"><a href="updatenewdue.php?ID=<?php echo $row_updatenewdue['ID']; ?>">UPDATE</a>
  </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

What i want to do is, to get the new input data from the form and add it to the data saved in amount column based on its ID in the table and update the new calculated data to that particular amount column. But its not working.

Here is my php code:-

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db ("store_records", $con);
if(isset($_GET['ID']))
{
$id=$_GET['ID'];
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM due_payments WHERE ID='$id'";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$amount2=$row['amount'];
$p_date=$_POST['pdate'];
$newdue=$_POST['newdue'];
$newamount=$amount2+$newdue;
$sql_query = "UPDATE due_payments SET date='$p_date', amount='$newamount' WHERE ID='$id'";
}
?>
```

How can i make the codes correct so that i can get the calculation done and update the data on the table??

Comment: Which version on php you are using `mysql_connect` is removed from latest php version.

Comment: i m using PHP/5.4.3

Comment: And what error you are getting with your current code ?

Comment: It doesn't show any error.. it just loads the page that is connected to the update button.

Comment: You have missing inputs to go with the POST arrays in the question and we don't know if those are correct or not. Any which way; you've been given an answer, ask them. If that doesn't solve it, then you'll need to post your full code and db schema. What you posted as a screenshot, isn't a db schema, it's only row values. *"It doesn't show any error"* - You're not checking for them via PHP and MySQL and you never executed that UPDATE query neither. If and when you do and it doesn't update it, then you may have syntax errors or column constraints.

Comment: I also see `echo $row_updatenewdue` and `$row=mysql_fetch_array`. If those are to be used in conjunction with each other, it's failing.

Comment: You have errors and don't even know it. The answer below didn't change the name attribute or the POST array's name and didn't query the UPDATE. So, look up PHP error reporting and mysql_error() and apply that to your codes. I'd post an answer, but have decided not to in regards to too many unknowns. Good luck with this. By the way; does that SELECT even work?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing so much wrongs, any way I just tell your problem
Use your id in an input field and submit it with others

```
<form name=updateamount method=post action="updatenewdue.php">
<table width="500" >
    <tr>
      <td width="161">New Due Amount: </td>
      <td width="329"><label>
        <input name="new_due" type="text" class="StyleTxtField" id="new_due">
      </label></td>
    </tr>
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row_updatenewdue['ID']; ?>">
<tr>
  <td><div align="center"><button name="submit" type="submit">UPDATE</button>
  </div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

IN your updatenewdue.php

```
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db ("store_records", $con);
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$id=$_POST['id'];
$sql_query="SELECT * FROM due_payments WHERE ID='$id'";
$result_set=mysql_query($sql_query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
$amount2=$row['amount'];
$p_date=$_POST['pdate'];
$newdue=$_POST['new_due'];
$newamount=$amount2+$newdue;
$sql_query = "UPDATE due_payments SET date='$p_date', amount='$newamount' WHERE ID='$id'";
}
```

**NB:I KNOW MYSQL IS DEPRICATED BUT I AM HELPING A BEGINNER**

Comment: where is `pdate` in your form

Comment: $p_date=$_POST['pdate']; may be that is your problem

Comment: @SanoojT `name="new_due"` and `$_POST['newdue']` are two different animals here. Plus, the UPDATE never gets executed. The OP also left out too much information/code in the question. Then your `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` suggestion won't work; there's no matching name attribute for it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for the suggessions I updated your suggessions

Comment: @SanoojT You're welcome. However, the UPDATE still doesn't get executed, it's missing `mysql_query()` for it. If that still doesn't solve the person's code, then they need to check for errors. They're obviously are not checking for them.